# Node.js append a row to xlsx file

Tags: node.js, macos, append, xlsx, exceljs

I'm just trying to figure out how to append a single row to an xlsx file. For example, append `array = [1 2 3 4 5]` to the first empty row using columns 1,2,3,4,5. Ideally I'd start with an empty `.xlsx` file, and repeatedly rerun this program, which appends a new row to the file each time it is ran.

I'm attempting to use exceljs, but any test writes I try to do to a file say corrupted when I attempt to open them.

edited code (still not working):

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('rssi');                                                                                                                                                                                                  
file = 'testfile.xlsx'          
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
sheet.addRow(array)
workbook.xlsx.writeFile(file)
.then(function() {
    console.log('Array added and file saved.')
});
```

Output is zero bytes and cannot be opened by Microsoft Excel. Says, "The file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you was trying to add the row in method which was called after file write. Try this example:

```
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();                                                                                                                                                                                                      
file = 'testfile.xlsx'
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('rssi');
sheet.addRow(array)
workbook.xlsx.writeFile(file)
       .then(function() {
           console.log('Array added and then file saved.')
       });
```

Comment: hmm this isn't seem to work. Now the file has a blank name and still says "excel cannot open this file"

Comment: @Jake I am using online google spreadsheets for opening. Works perfect. Which excel version do you use?

Comment: Using Excel for Mac Version 15.26

Comment: One thing I notice is that if I don't add `.xlsx` to the `file` var it just creates a data file, but if instead I use the full `testfile.xlsx`, it looks like it creates a .xlsx file, although it actually says .xlsx, whereas the other known working files I have of that type have the file type hidden

Comment: It also says that it's zero bytes

Comment: @Jake, can you please update your post with whole working code?

Comment: @Jake, I think you also trying to write to file while it opened in your excel desktop app. Try close file (and excel just to be sure), run code, and open in excel again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127746/discussion-between-aring-and-jake).

Answer (score 0):

> But it add only one row at a time

```
var spread_sheet = require('spread_sheet');

var row = "1,2,Jack,Pirate";
var filePath = '/home/Pranjal/Desktop/test.xlsx';
var sheetName = "Sheet1";

spread_sheet.addRow(row,filePath,sheetName,function(err,result){
console.log(err,result)
})
```

Comment: spread_sheet module works for .odc extension also, apart from .xlsx  extension

Answer (score -1):

**Add row to spreadsheet:-**

I also stuck with the same functionality issue, so I used 'spread_sheet' module.

It worked for me

Comment: Please explain how to use 'spread_sheet' module, as this answer may be viewed by future visitors.

Comment: // But it add only one row at a time

var spread_sheet = require('spread_sheet');


var row = "1,2,Jack,Pirate";

var filePath = '/home/Pranjal/Desktop/test.xlsx';

var sheetName = "Sheet1";


spread_sheet.addRow(row,filePath,sheetName,function(err,result){

console.log(err,result)

})

Comment: Please don't put it in comments, instead edit your answer